# How to add html content to html layout in LWR

Tags: salesforcedx, lwr, lwr-oss

After creating the LWR project I updated the lwr.config.json to point to .html template for the route "/". After I update the contenet template to a .html file too as bellow

```
 {
        "id": "Home",
        "path": "/",
        "contentTemplate": "$contentDir/about.html",
        "layoutTemplate": "$layoutsDir/main.html"
    }
```

project loads the main.html but not the about.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="$assetsDir/css/main.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
 
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Home</a>
                    <li><a href="/about">About</a>
                    <li><a href="/explore">Explore</li>
                     <li><a href="//developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/overview">Learn LWR</a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <main>
                {{ body | safe }}
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What should I need to do to add html inside html layout?